# В чём преимущество vue-axios по сравнению с чистым axois?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Попробую [примеры](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html) из документации vuejs на тему создания http-запросов при помощи axios.

```
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then(response => (this.info = response.data.bpi))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Также на просторах интернета (например, в том же [real world application](https://github.com/gothinkster/vue-realworld-example-app)) попадаются примеры, когда в vue-приложение ставится не только axios, но ещё и vue-axios (см на [гитхабе](https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios)):

```
  mounted() {
    Vue.axios.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then(response => (this.info = response.data.bpi))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Типа, библиотека vue-axios нужна "для более удобной интеграции axois с vue".

Я как-то глядя на эти два примера не особо вижу каких-то преимуществ и этой самой "интеграции". Возможно, я слишком простой пример сижу разбираю, но как-то мне неочевидно в чём плюсы.

Кто-нибудь понимает в чём преимущества vue-axios перед чистым axios, может пояснить?

Comment: Нет преимуществ (функционал библиотеки `vue-axios` фактически можно реализовать в две строчки), в предыдущих vue news была статья про это: https://dev.to/heftyhead/lets-talk-about-an-unnecessary-but-popular-vue-plugin-1ied

Comment: @diraria Спасибо за ссылку, любопытно.